# youtube's generated url for searching video name in android apps

Tags: android, video, youtube

First, im blind when it comes to youtube API on Android, so please bear with me.

I have done a lot of searching using keywords like "search youtube video url android", but i still cant find how to find the youtube's videos by their name/title.

I just found that i can get the videos based on their **uploader** by using this code :

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc");
```

However, what i want is to search by their title/name, not by their uploader.

I will be very happy if you have some good tutorial about this youtube on Android.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your help :D**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

To find something manually on YouTube, you have to search something like https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query= + "video name". But you have to replace spaces with + sign.

Try this code -

```
public String VideoUrl (String url) {

    String VideoName = VideoName.replaceAll(" ", "+");

    VideoName = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + VideoName;

    return VideoName;

}
```